# Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node (RPC & web3.js)

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am trying to access my Geth node through RPC from my UI (using web3.js)

My Geth command is:

---

`geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --rpccorsdomain "*"`

---

In the front-end :

---

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("localhost:8501"));
```

---

I am getting error:

---

[image]

---

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the wildcard inside the rpccorsdomain expanded by shell? Can you do a 'ps' and grep to find out the actual argument?

Comment: Are you loading your page from localhost or some other domain?

Comment: @Ismael using Node http-server and loading the page from localhost:8080 .. I tried to change --rpccorsdomain "*"  to --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8080" in geth command and it works!

Comment: @Bilel Please add your solution as an answer so it can help others with a similar problem.